# Updating forms dynamically in rails using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that allows a user to select a supplier(freelancer), a type of service that is required and a number of shifts that the supplier(freelancer) will be working. Depending on which service is selected and how many shifts the freelancer is required for, I need to change the total amount of the request dynamically.

**UPDATE**

On the Service model, there is a column named rate which holds a value(an integer). Within my form, I need to be able to grab the rate value to calculate the total amount on the client side.

Request belongs_to Service and Service has_many Requests.

This is my code so far:

form:

```
= f.label :supplier_id
= f.collection_select :supplier_id, Supplier.all, :id, :business_name, {prompt: true}, required: true, class: 'form-control select'
= f.label :service_id
= f.collection_select :service_id, Service.all, :id, :name, {prompt: true}, required: true, class: 'form-control select'
= f.label :shifts
= f.text_field :shifts, required: true, class: 'form-control datepicker'
= f.label :total_amout  
= f.text_field :total_amout, readonly: true, class: 'form-control'
```

javascript:

```
function updateCost() {
    var total_shifts = $('#booking_shifts').val().length;
    var service_rate = $('select#booking_service_id :selected').data('rate')

    var total = service_rate * total_shifts

    $('#booking_total_amount').val(total);
}
$('#booking_shifts').change(function(){ updateCost(); })
```

In the *total amount* field I am getting *NaN*

In the console when I do:

```
$('select#booking_service_id :selected').data('rate');
```

I am getting *Undefined*

And when I am trying:

```
$('select#booking_service_id :selected').data();
```

I am getting *{}* empty hash

Could you please advise how can I get the rate of selected service and store it into a variable *service_rate* in order to do the maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out:

In the form, I have changed *collection_select* to *select* with *options_to_select* like this:

```
= f.select :service_id, options_for_select(@services.map{ |s| [s.name, s.id, {'data-rate'=>s.rate}] }, selected_key = f.object.service_id), {prompt: true}, {class: 'form-control select'}
```

And then I was able to retrieve the data that I was looking for with javascript like this:

```
function updateCost() {
    var total_shifts = $('#booking_shifts').val().length;
    var service_rate = $('select#booking_service_id :selected').data('rate');

    var total = parseInt(service_rate) * total_shifts

    $('#booking_total_amout').val(total);
}
$('#booking_shifts').change(function(){
        updateCost();
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the problem is the way you are selecting the rate. to get the rate im asuming the rate is the value of the option. You should use the following query

```
var service_rate = $( "#booking_service_id option:selected" ).text();
```

Now since that value is text youll need to parse it to int

```
var total = parseInt(service_rate) * total_shifts
```

total should contain the value you are expecting.

Hope it Helps

Comment: This is much better Sudakatux, but I would like to get the rate of the Service rather than the name of the Service. I have updated my post and the code but still not quite there.